# SharePoint site not getting indexed

Tags: sharepoint-online

Due to a requirement I have set the option "Allow this site to appear in search results?" to No. Later I have changed that options to Yes, but none of the site content are not retrieved by search. I have re-indexed the site and a list as well and still those are not indexed. Now 24 hours gone after making it to yes.

Appreciate if anyone can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if your search account  and content access that you use has **FULL read access** to your web applications. Also, make sure your read access to **User profile service Applications** as well as **People** search working.

And i see you've already have set  "Allow this site to appear in search results?" to Yes.

Could you check if you set " Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" to yes as well ?

Here are the steps on how to set up document library to appear in search results:

1. As an admin, locate the library that's missing from search results.
2. Click the gear icon () in the upper-right corner.
3. Select Library Settings.
4. Select Advanced Settings.
5. Make sure that Allow items from this document library to appear in
   search results? is set to Yes.

After the setting is set to Yes, the library should be indexed during the next scheduled crawl.

For more detailed info please review [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2008449/search-doesn-t-return-all-results-in-sharepoint-online)